# How to add a div as the 2nd to last div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I know that .append puts the code at the end, and .prepend puts it in the front, but I have 5 divs within a parent div, and I want some html code to be added dynamically right before the last child div. How can I do that?

Comment: How will you append a parent to its last child?

Comment: I don't want to append the parent div... I'm appending another div

Comment: changed my wording to make it more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#parent > div:last-child').before('<span>something</span>');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm97U/).

You can flip the whole thing around too.

```
$('<span>something</span>').insertBefore('#parent > div:last-child');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#main div:last-child').before("yourhtmlhere");
```

http://api.jquery.com/before/

Comment: This will select `div` within a `div` as well (which may not be what the OP wants).

Answer (score 0):

Use insert Before. Refer [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore) for more.

```
var insertedElement = parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:last` pseudo selector and the `.before()` method

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Aq6eu/

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div> child div 1</div>
    <div> child div 2</div>
    <div> child div 3</div>
    <div> child div 4</div>
    <div> child div 5</div>
</div>

$('#parent div:last').before('some text goes here ')
```